# Find the covariance

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, covariance

> Say $X_t$ is a time series. Find the autocovariance function for $\Delta X_t$ using explicit methods.

I get:

$$ Cov(X_{t}-X_{t-1},X_{t-k}-X_{t-1-k}))=Cov(X_t,X_{t-k}) - Cov(X_t,X_{t-1-k})-Cov(X_{t-1},X_{t-k}) + Cov(X_{t-1},X_{t-1-k})$$

However the solution says it should be $2\gamma_k - \gamma_{k-1}-\gamma_{k+1}$. I know that $Cov(X_t,X_{t-k})=\gamma_k$, and it makes sense for $Cov(X_t,X_{t-1-k})=\gamma_{k-1}$ from this by substitution. But I am unsure of the other terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For weakly stationary processes $$\gamma_k = \text{Cov}(X_{t+k}, X_t).$$
The subscript for gamma is just the lag. To find it, take the time subscript on the left and subtract the subscript on the right, inside the covariance operator’s parentheses.

Comment: So $Cov(X_{t-1},X_{t-k}) = Cov(X_{t},X_{t-k+1}) = \gamma_{k+1}  $?

Comment: Is $t-1-(t-k)$ equal to $t-(t-k+1)$ equal to $k+1$?